# Pure JS: display overlay over elements on hover using mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: javascript, hover, overlay, mouseenter, mouseleave

I wonder if there is a pure JS way to display overlays in the same fashion as google webdev tools (Elements tab) do.

I posted a year ago here a script that does the job but using jQuery, this script is somewhat buggy, now I want a pure JS script, this will follow...

Comment: body :hover {background: rgba(0,0,100, 0.1)} is easier and less destructive to the page's interactivity...

Comment: I don't understand, does this style do the same thing as the script bellow? If it is the case I have to update my browser of emergency!

Comment: you probably mean: 
body *:hover {background: rgba(0,0,100, 0.1)}
;-)

Comment: yes but no, in fact I need to do further things with these overlays, thanks for your remark
note that for some websites like facebook.com, my script works better ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pure JS script:

```
function getElementWithDOMId(DOMId)
{
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++)
  {
    if (allElements[i].getAttribute('DOMId') == DOMId)
    {
        return allElements[i];
    }
  }
}
function offset( elem ) {
    var docElem, win,
        box = { top: 0, left: 0 },
        doc = elem && elem.ownerDocument;

    docElem = doc.documentElement;

    if ( typeof elem.getBoundingClientRect !== typeof undefined ) {
        box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
    win = getWindow( doc );
    return {
        top: box.top + win.pageYOffset - docElem.clientTop,
        left: box.left + win.pageXOffset - docElem.clientLeft
    };
};

function getWindow( elem ) {
    return isWindow( elem ) ? elem : elem.nodeType === 9 && elem.defaultView;
}

function isWindow( obj ) {
    return obj != null && obj === obj.window;
}
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
var data = [];
function allDescendants (node, tags, nodes) {
    nodes = nodes || [];
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var child = node.childNodes[i];
      if(inArray(node.tagName, tags) && !node.hasAttribute('DOMId')) {
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);
        node.setAttribute('DOMId', rand);
        elWidth = node.offsetWidth;
        elHeight = node.offsetHeight;
        elLeft = offset(node).left;
        elTop = offset(node).top;
        TagName = node.tagName;
        data.push(Array(
            rand,
            {x: elLeft,         y: elTop},
            {x: elLeft+elWidth, y: elTop},
            {x: elLeft+elWidth, y: elTop+elHeight},
            {x: elLeft,         y: elTop+elHeight},
            false,
            {w: elWidth,        h: elHeight},
            {tagName: TagName}
        ))
      }
      allDescendants(child, tags, nodes);
    }
}
function addOverlay(node, id) {
    console.debug('adding overlay with props width %d, height %d, left %d and top %d', node.offsetWidth, node.offsetHeight, offset(node).left, offset(node).top);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.width = node.offsetWidth + 'px';
    div.style.height = node.offsetHeight + 'px';
    div.style.top = offset(node).top + 'px';
    div.style.left = offset(node).left + 'px';
    div.style.background = "#9fc4e7";
    div.style.border = '2px solid black';
    div.style['-moz-opacity'] = 0.1;
    div.style.opacity = 0.1;
    div.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=10)';
    div.setAttribute('id',id);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
};
allDescendants(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],['DIV','SPAN','H1','H2','H3','H4','TABLE','TD','TR','A','UL','LI','OL','INPUT','TEXTAREA','P','CODE','IMG', 'PRE']);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    for (i in data) {
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
        if((x>data[i][1].x) & (x<data[i][2].x) & (y>data[i][1].y) & (y<data[i][3].y) & (!data[i][5]))  {
            addOverlay(getElementWithDOMId(data[i][0]), data[i][0]);
            data[i][5] = true;
        } else if(((x<data[i][1].x) | (x>data[i][2].x) | (y<data[i][1].y) | (y>data[i][3].y)) & (data[i][5])) {
            document.getElementById(data[i][0]).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(data[i][0]));
            data[i][5] = false;  
        }
    }
});
```